# SOAP web service using emulator

Tags: soap, service, web

I am implementing soap web service but have to use emulator to make it work and generate the java bean file from the WSDL file. Please as I am new to SOAP can anyone guide me on how to do this in eclipse project. The WSDL supplied is complaining of wrong schema location which I don't have access to the server but I was asked to use emulator.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Mit XMLSpy v2013 (http://www.altova.com) von thilo gaul (ltur) bearbeitet -->
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2 (branches/2.2-7015; 2012-02-20T20:31:25+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:pws="http://www.peakwork.net/pws/2010/03" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="PWS" targetNamespace="http://www.peakwork.net/pws/2010/03">
    <wsdl:documentation>
        The wsdl for the PeakWork PHub.
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.peakwork.net/pws/2010/03">
            <include schemaLocation="http://213.144.19.50:80/pwsLMR/2010/03/?xsd=34"/>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightGroupRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="fgr" element="pws:FlightGroupRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightGroupResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="fgr" element="pws:FlightGroupResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightProductRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="fpr" element="pws:FlightProductRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightProductResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="fpr" element="pws:FlightProductResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="for" element="pws:FlightOfferRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="for" element="pws:FlightOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightVariantRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="fvr" element="pws:FlightVariantRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightVariantResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="fvr" element="pws:FlightOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightMatrixRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="fmr" element="pws:FlightMatrixRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFlightMatrixResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="fmr" element="pws:FlightOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelGroupRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="hgr" element="pws:HotelGroupRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelGroupResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="hgr" element="pws:ProductGroupResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelProductRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="hpr" element="pws:HotelProductRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelProductResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="hpr" element="pws:HotelProductResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="hor" element="pws:HotelOfferRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="hor" element="pws:HotelOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelVariantRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="hvr" element="pws:HotelVariantRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelVariantResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="hvr" element="pws:HotelOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelMatrixRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="hmr" element="pws:HotelMatrixRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelMatrixResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="hmr" element="pws:HotelOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageGroupRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="pgr" element="pws:PackageGroupRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageGroupResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="pgr" element="pws:ProductGroupResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageProductRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="ppr" element="pws:PackageProductRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageProductResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="ppr" element="pws:PackageProductResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="por" element="pws:PackageOfferRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="por" element="pws:PackageOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageVariantRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="pvr" element="pws:PackageVariantRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageVariantResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="pvr" element="pws:PackageOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageMatrixRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="pmr" element="pws:PackageMatrixRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageMatrixResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="pmr" element="pws:PackageOfferResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageFlightRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="pvr" element="pws:PackageFlightRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageFlightResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="pvr" element="pws:PackageFlightResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageFlightAlternativesRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="pfar" element="pws:PackageFlightAlternativesRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageFlightAlternativesResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="pfar" element="pws:PackageFlightAlternativesResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetCheckStatusRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="csr" element="pws:CheckStatusRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetCheckStatusResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="csr" element="pws:CheckStatusResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFormDataRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="fdr" element="pws:FormDataRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetFormDataResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="fdr" element="pws:FormDataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHelpRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="help" element="pws:HelpRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHelpResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="help" element="pws:HelpResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetInfoRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="info" element="pws:InfoRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetInfoResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="info" element="pws:InfoResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="PHubPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightGroup">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFlightGroupRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFlightGroupResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightProduct">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFlightProductRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFlightProductResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightOffer">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFlightOfferRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFlightOfferResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightVariant">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFlightVariantRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFlightVariantResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightMatrix">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFlightMatrixRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFlightMatrixResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelGroup">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelGroupRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelGroupResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelProduct">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelProductRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelProductResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelOffer">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelOfferRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelOfferResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelVariant">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelVariantRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelVariantResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelMatrix">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelMatrixRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelMatrixResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <!--
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelAllotment">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHotelAllotmentRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHotelAllotmentResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        -->
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageGroup">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageGroupRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageGroupResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageProduct">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageProductRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageProductResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageOffer">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageOfferRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageOfferResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageVariant">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageVariantRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageVariantResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageMatrix">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageMatrixRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageMatrixResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageFlight">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageFlightRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageFlightResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <!--
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageAllotment">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageAllotmentRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageAllotmentResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        -->
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageFlightAlternatives">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetPackageFlightAlternativesRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetPackageFlightAlternativesResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCheckStatus">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetCheckStatusRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetCheckStatusResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFormData">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetFormDataRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetFormDataResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHelp">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetHelpRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetHelpResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetInfo">
            <wsdl:input message="pws:GetInfoRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="pws:GetInfoResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="PHubBinding" type="pws:PHubPortType">
        <wsdlsoap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <!--
        <wsdlsoap12:binding style="document"
                            transport="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/" />
     -->
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightGroup">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFlightGroup"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightProduct">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFlightProduct"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightOffer">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFlightOffer"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightVariant">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFlightVariant"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFlightMatrix">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFlightMatrix"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelGroup">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelGroup"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelProduct">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelProduct"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelOffer">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelOffer"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelVariant">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelVariant"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelMatrix">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelMatrix"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <!--
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHotelAllotment">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHotelAllotment" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        -->
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageGroup">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageGroup"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageProduct">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageProduct"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageOffer">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageOffer"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageVariant">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageVariant"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageMatrix">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageMatrix"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageFlight">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageFlight"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <!--
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageAllotment">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageAllotment" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        -->
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPackageFlightAlternatives">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPackageFlightAlternatives"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCheckStatus">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getCheckStatus"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetFormData">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getFormData"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetHelp">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getHelp"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetInfo">
            <wsdlsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:getInfo"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="PHubService">
        <wsdl:port name="PHubPort" binding="pws:PHubBinding">
            <wsdlsoap12:address location="http://213.144.19.50:80/pwsLMR/2010/03/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <!--
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelAllotmentRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="har" element="pws:HotelAllotmentRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHotelAllotmentResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="har" element="pws:HotelAllotmentResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
-->
    <!--
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageAllotmentRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="par" element="pws:PackageAllotmentRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetPackageAllotmentResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="par" element="pws:PackageAllotmentResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
-->
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you post more detail such as the supplied WSDL code, your attempt to get it to work, any errors received etc. It will be very hard for anyone to help you without these.

Comment: @Ren I have posted the supplied WSDL code above in my question now. What I want to do is to use top-down approach to generate the Java bean file using the wsdl but the wsdl error gives "Failed to the read document: <include schemaLocation="http://213.144.19.50:80/pwsLMR/2010/03/?xsd=34"/>. the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>

Comment: @Ren also I tried to download SOAPsonar emulator to use it to run the service but how I capture the wsdl file so that I can set the path in wsdl to be able to run it and use it to generate the Java bean file and the artifacts